# Microsoft.office.interop.msproject works fine in my local pc and does not work after deploy my app to azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, ms-project

I have an asp.net core5 web application in this application I am using both Microsoft.office.interop.excel library and Microsoft.office.interop.msproject library to create excel files and .mpp files they all works fine on my local development pc, but after deploying my application to azure or to somee.com or to smarterasp.net.com the excel library works fine and I can create excel files from my application, but msproject library does not work on any server, I have searched very much to get a solution in vent, I'd be appreciated for any help. Thanks

Comment: Is Excel installed on that target machine where you are running that inter-op code? Those inter-op assemblies that you reference in your project ONLY allow you to use and interface to Excel. You still need to go get a copy of office and install Excel on that target computer running your code, and of course using a copy of Excel. So, on that target web server, you not only need to use those "inter-op assemblies" referenced, you in addtion to that need a full blown legal copy of Excel also installed on that target machine. So this works on your dev box since you no doubt have Excel installed.

Comment: Thanks Albert for quick reply, how to put a copy of ms project into the target web server? note that my problem is with ms project not excel, excel works fine

Comment: ms project? I thought you were using Excel? But it really don't matter. If you using word, or excel or whatever program on that server? Then you need to go get a copy of office and install Excel, or word or whatever program you are expecting your inter-op code to work with. I mean, how this works is like any computer. If you need Excel or word on that computer, then you install word or excel on that computer. So whatever program your inter-op is using, then that program has to be installed on that computer like any other software you plan to use on that computer.

Comment: So yes, you need to get a copy of ms-project and install it on that same computer where the web site is running from.

Comment: Yes, I need to install ms-project on azure or any server which can host my web application, how to achieve this.

Comment: Depends on what kind of Azure hosting you are using. You need a whole VM server in your plan. Then that is just a server computer in which you can remote into, and do whatever you want with that hosted server VM. I mean, if you need some PDF viewer on your android phone, then you have to install a PDF viewer on that phone, right? So how this works for setting up a web server is much the same. I mean, with a low cost web hosting plan, you can't install software onto that server. So if you write some software with MySQL, PHP etc? Then you find a hosting plan with that software (linux)

Comment: I can go find a low cost windows .net hosting plan (super cheap). But then again, if that server has MySQL and I am using SQL server, that will not work. I mean your web server is just  computer - it comes down to you picking the right hosting plan based on the tools your used (say Linux tools and thus Linux hosting, or say windows hosting, and thus .net software). However, unless that hosting plan allows additional software to be installed, then you can't. So, one way is to go with higher cost hosting, and use a server - you can then install IIS web server or whatever you want to that server.

Comment: you can find the redistributable here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3508  (if you just want the DLL you need you can extract the .msi using 7-zip and get what you want... for instance for excell, extract EXCELLPIA.DLL)

Comment: however, going through COM is not all that efficient... instead I'd suggest using something like Apache's POI.